# Bypassing dialog bug in Android

Tags: android, dialog

I have an application which in certain areas, a dialog pops up and restricts the user from proceeding. There are currently two types of dialogs. One restricts the user entirely from proceeding and the other allows the user to proceed if they click on "OK".

**The problem:**

When the dialog appears, if I close the application and relaunch it, the app bypasses the dialog and gains access to the next screen. On one of the cases, the app bypasses the screen and shows that screen which the user was previously on before the dialog appeared.

Does anyone have an idea what may be the problem?

Comment: You need to call that same preventive function in definition of "onResume()" in concerned activity class.

Comment: Hmmm yes I see your point. +1 for the quick and promising deduction.

Comment: But why does the dialog not stay there? Is it because it's not an actual Activity/Fragment that it gets recycled? It makes sense if I look at it that way.

Comment: It's developer's responsibility to maintain state of an App. Android OS is not  responsible for that, Android OS responsibility ends at providing sandboxing.